# Create a menu item with arguments

Tags: 7, routes

I am trying to manually create a menu link item in the User Menu that contains a wildcard, But I cant make it work.  I can get it to work if I have a static path, but I cant get it to work with wildcards args

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/bookmarks'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Bookmarks',
    'description' => 'Link to My Bookmarks',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu'
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. What do you mean by, "manually create"? How are you trying to create the menu item?

Comment: Through function hook_menu in a custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to use user wildcards first, I too came across this problem; and after some trial and error, found that the `%user` wildcard doesn't work with the menu type [MENU_NORMAL_ITEM](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_NORMAL_ITEM/7), instead it works if the type is [MENU_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7).

So, the code should be:

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/bookmarks'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Bookmarks',
    'description' => 'Link to My Bookmarks',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu'
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Usually, this menu type is rendered as a tab in user menu.

I didn't get enough time to figure out why it doesn't work with MENU_LOCAL_TASK, but when I do find the reason, I'll post it back.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  This is a link to a view, and I already have a Tab to it configured in the view...but you cant add more than one menu item in the view, so Ill just reverse it.  Ill put the Menu Item link in the view, and use MENU_LOCAL_TASK for the tab.

Comment: It works for user/%user, and that is a `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` menu item, as its type is not explicitly defined. See [user_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu/7).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define the page callback for that menu item, which means Drupal will use the one for the parent menu item, as reported in the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) documentation.

> **"page callback"**: The function to call to display a web page when the user visits the path. If omitted, the parent menu item's callback will be used instead.

As the parent menu item for user/%user/bookmarks is user/%user, this means that, instead of showing the page you want, Drupal is showing the user profile page.

As you are creating a menu item for a view, there is normally no need to implement `hook_menu()`, as a view can be associated with a menu item.

[image: screenshot]

If you need to show the view using more than one menu item, just clone the page, and change the path for the cloned page. With two pages, you will be able to use two menu items; with three pages, you will be able to use three menu items.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: does this mean that if _'page callback'_ is specified the menu items can be rendered as `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`? I'm talking specifically when we use `%user` wildcards.

Comment: The overhead of cloning a view is too high, just for adding 1 menu item.  One more view is one more export, which means unnecessary code being in version control

Comment: I read that wrong.  I thought you were saying to clone the view, but you said clone the page.  But still, cloning the page just for a menu item seems really unnecessary.

Comment: @indrock I tried with node/%node/bookmarks, `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`, and "navigation" as menu name. The link appears, but it points to node/bookmarks. I tried with user/%/bookmarks, and the link doesn't appear between the links I can enable for the "navigation" menu. The strange is that blog/%user_uid_optional (used from the Blog module) appears, and links to the correct page. It is more complicated than "if the menu path contains %user, it doesn't work."

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks. This is interesting and strange at the same time.